# Ritz projection error estimate for bilinear Lagrange element?

Tags: finite-element, numerics

For second order elliptic problem
\begin{align}
-\Delta u=f,\quad in ~~\Omega\\
u=0,\quad on~~ \partial\Omega,
\end{align}
we have for the Ritz projection for $P_1$ conforming element
\begin{align}
\|u-R_hu\|_{W^{0,p}}+h\|u-R_hu\|_{W^{1,p}}\leq Ch^2\| u \|_{W^{2,p}}，\quad u\in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)\cap W^{2,p}(\Omega).
\end{align}
Does this error estimate also hold for bilinear $Q_1$ element?

Comment: You did not define the "Ritz projection". However, this looks like a superconvergence result, because typically for linear elements you get $O(h)$. What you have here, $O(h^2)$, is common for quadratic elements.

Comment: For a quasi-uniform rectangular partition $\mathcal{T}_h$ for rectangular domain $\Omega$. The bilinear Lagrange finite element  space is
\begin{align*}
V_h=\{v_h\in C(\bar{\Omega}),v_h|_{K}\in span\{1,x,y,xy\},v_h|_{\partial\Omega}=0\}.
\end{align*}
And the Ritz projection is 
\begin{align*}
(\nabla(u-R_hu),\nabla v_h)=0,\quad \forall v_h\in V_h.
\end{align*}

Comment: @knl no, that is the standard rate (note that $W^{0,p} = L^p$ -- for which you get $h^2$ using the Aubin--Nitsche trick -- and that the $W^{1,p}$ norm is multiplied by $h$, so by canceling you get the expected rate of $h$ only)

Comment: see Theorem 5.9 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.08618 (shameless plug). And, yes, the the same rate holds for bilinear elements, see Brenner and Scott, Chapter 4.6 (in the third edition).

Comment: I'm quite sure there wasn't $h$ in front of the second term when I read it first. Oh well, my mistake.

Comment: Looking at the edit history I wasn't crazy after all!